# Abstract class, abstract method parameters and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I joined a research project in which the [OOQP library](https://github.com/emgertz/OOQP/blob/master/src/Vector/OoqpVector.h) is used. It uses an abstract class `OoqpVector` (inherited by several subclasses) and a number of methods, such as:

`virtual double dotProductWith(OoqpVector& v) = 0`

This method is implemented by subclasses `SimpleVector` and `DistributedVector`. Because of genericity, `OoqpVector::dotProductWith` **allows** all possible combinations:

- `SimpleVector.dotProductWith(SimpleVector)`
- `DistributedVector.dotProductWith(DistributedVector)`
- `SimpleVector.dotProductWith(DistributedVector)`
- `DistributedVector.dotProductWith(SimpleVector)`

However in practice, the method is called on vectors of the **same type** only (combinations 1 and 2). Therefore, the authors implemented `SimpleVector::dotProductWith(OoqpVector&)` and `DistributedVector::dotProductWith(OoqpVector&)` by **dynamically casting** the parameter to the current type.

Although this works, I find it a bit ugly and wonder if we can implement the same behavior without casts.

An option would be to get rid of `OoqpVector::dotProductWith`, declare the specialized methods `SimpleVector::dotProductWith(SimpleVector&)` and `DistributedVector::dotProductWith(DistributedVector&)`, and force the calling methods to impose the two vector types to be equal. However, our code uses a bunch of OoqpVectors everywhere and is relatively generic, so this might be difficult to achieve.

Do you see a way to fix that?
Best,

Charlie